# PHP Post to ASP Form, return XML results to PHP page.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asp-classic, cross-domain

The setup of what i have to work with and what i need is as below:

- I have been provided with an ASP form (**on another domain**) which upon submission outputs search results in an **XML** format.
- I am developing a PHP website (**on my companies domain**)
- From this PHP website i need to be able to query the said ASP form and get the XML results posted back to the PHP page (**on my companies domain**)
- The variable "Client=***" must be sent to the ASP form, for it to work.

**What i have tried so far...**

- jQuery.ajax to try and do a normal post request using this code:

  ```
  $.ajax({
  url: "http://www.example.com/xml/aspfile.asp",
  crossDomain: true,
  cache: false,
  dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
  data: { Client: "clientname" etc },
  type: 'post',
  xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
  },
  error: function(){
      alert("error");
  },
  success: function(data){
      var xml;
      if (typeof data == "string") {
          xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
          xml.async = false;
          xml.loadXML(data);
      } else {
          xml = data;
      }
  } });
  ```

*Note:*

I have tried alot of different iterations of the above code from basic ajax requests to more complex ones like the above.

The above code returns the following error, which is an error i have come across quite a bit.

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{14ce834e-ef24-43f8-b338-7202241298a5} Line Number 1, Column 1:^
```

**What i need**

Ideally some code that works ... failing that ideas or suggestions on how i can get this to work.

Many thanks in advance to all those that post answers for your time.

**Edit: As requested here is how the XML looks**

```
<quicksearchresults>
        <heading>
            <title1>River Cruises</title1>
            <title2>Quick Search</title2>
            <cruise_nos>732</cruise_nos>
            <earliest_date>01/08/11</earliest_date>
            <latest_date>01/09/11</latest_date>
            <river>Anywhere</river>
            <linename>Any</linename>
        </heading>
        <rivercruiselist>
            <holdate>28/08/11</holdate>
            <linename>The River Cruise Line</linename>
            <shipname>Esmerelda</shipname>
            <shiplink>url</shiplink>
            <cruisename>Cruise+The+Danube+to+Vienna+%26+Budapest</cruisename>
            <cruiselink>url</cruiselink>
            <river>Danube</river>
            <ratingicon>Images/BudgetIcon.png</ratingicon>
            <flyfrom>Linz</flyfrom>
            <flyback>linz</flyback>
            <cruisenights>7</cruisenights>
            <vacationdays>10</vacationdays>
            <lowprice>0</lowprice>
            <highprice>0</highprice>
            <flights>including Coach</flights>
            <soldout>Yes</soldout>
            <enquiryformlink>url</enquiryformlink>
            <enquiryformimage>Images/TravelEButton.png</enquiryformimage>
        </rivercruiselist>
</quicksearchresults>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what the XML returned looks like? From the error it looks like you aren't getting a result back, or it's malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your PHP server as a proxy: you make a AJAX request to your own PHP page which uses curl to get the XML from the external source and returns it you, so you can parse it.

```
var xml;
if (typeof data == "string") {
    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xml.async = false;
    xml.loadXML(data);
} else {
    xml = data;
}
```

This part is not necessary, you can use jQuery selectors to parse the XML. From the looks of it your request isn't returning any results. What does `alert(xml)` produce?
AFAIK you cannot do a cross-domain POST, you can do cross-domain `GET` with some `JSONP` hacks though.

Your example XML does not appear to be valid as the first `<quicksearchresults>` node is never closed.

Here's an example, you'll have to excuse my broken PHP, as I haven't used it in a while.

```
// post the contents of the form to our PHP proxy

    $.post("myproxy.php", $("#myform").serialize, function(data) {
    // do something with returned xml here.

    },"xml");
```

Proxy example (myproxy.php):

```
 <?php 

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.remotedomain.com/api.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'client*' => 'something',
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
 ?>
```

Comment: I am using a jQuery pluging called xdomainajax.js which enables cross domain `POST` and `GET`. Im not entirely sure how to go about using my server as a proxy in your initial suggestion?

Comment: The XML is closed properly, for some reason i cant get the `</quicksearchresult>` to appear in the above.

Comment: Il give this answer a thumbs up as i could see it working. Unfortunetly its not solved my problem.

Comment: Im getting an error message saying that the page has been moved. This means that the ASP page hasnt auth'd me to perform the search. Also i cant seem to output any of the returned data.

Comment: does it work when you do the request via the browser? how do you regularly "authenticate"?  It might be that it's checking your user-agent or you have forgot to mention something. Sometimes 302 is a part of the regular authentication process.

Comment: @itsphil let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1953/discussion-between-uku-loskit-and-itsphil)

Comment: The answer above i believe more than often would be correct. After @Uku Loskit's help i have now narrowed down that the issue exists with the ASP file provider.